# display 7 div in 2 column

Tags: css, html, layout

I have a big div containing 7 divs

```
<div id="big_div">
  <div>a</div> <div>a</div> <div>a</div> 
  <div>b</div> <div>b</div> <div>b</div><div>b</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to display the 7 div in two column of 4 and 3 elements without editing the HTML, maybe using nth_child?

```
#big_div{
}

#big_div div{
}
```

Comment: do you mean column or rows? the way you have them laid out implies rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more modern solution if you need them in "columns" ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NWset/2)):

```
#big_div {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}

#big_div div:nth-child(3) { 
    -moz-column-break-after: always;
    -webkit-column-break-after: always;
    break-after: always;
}
```

[Have a look at browser support at caniuse](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn).

Answer (score 1):

```
#big_div{
     width: 100%;
     zoom:1;
}

#big_div div{
     float:left;
     width:50%;
}
#big_div:after{
     content:"";
     display:block;
     clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without adding html use the nth-child(1n+4), note nth-child will not work on all browsers (older IE browsers for example)

CSS

For Rows

```
#big_div{
     width: 100%;
}

#big_div div{
     float:left;
     width:33%; //(100% / 3 )
}

#big_div div:nth-child(1n+4){
     float:left;
     width:25%; //100% / 4
}
```